# vue.js component is not showing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a file EmptyComponent.html to show a Vue.js component (myComponent.vue) both files are in the same folder. my component will not show and I am always getting an error  in chrome developer tools console saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier EmptyComponent.html:8"

EmptyComponent.html

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <h1> id app div </h1>
      <myComponent></myComponent>
    </div>

    <script>
        import myComponent from 'myComponent.vue'


    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {myComponent}
    });
    </script>
```

myComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h1> myComponent div</h1>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'myComponent'

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use single file components `.vue` you should use [`Vue cli 3`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/), but your component does not contain a complex code you could use CDN and declare your component using `Vue.component('my-component',{....})` :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1> id app div </h1>
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>

<script>
  Vue.component('my-component', {

    template: `  <div>
      <h1> myComponent div</h1>

  </div>`
  })

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',

  });
</script>
```